# What is the best FME Transformer for Text search and replace in attribute fields

Tags: fme-form, text, transformer

I have a number of feature classes which have fields containing text which has somehow become improperly encoded.  The fields contain german text which should be either ä, ö, ü, ß but instead contains for instance KindergÃ¤rten instead of Kindergärten ...etc

What transformer best allows me to check the field for "Ã¤" and replaces it with ä?

Comment: Regular Expression Tester http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/Regular-Expression-Tester can be modified to change the German accented characters correctly.

Answer (score 4):

that's probably not done with one transformer. I'd use a ***StringSearcher*** or ***SubstringExtractor*** to get the characters that make Problems. You can then try if a ***StringReplacer*** can replace the characters. If again a the german characters are not replaced correctly you could analyse the ASCII code with the ***CharacterCodeExtractor*** and replace it with ***CharacterCodeReplacer***.
See doc of ***CharacterCodeExtractor***:

> CharacterCodeExtractor
>
> Extracts the integral character code of the first character in the
>   source string attribute, and adds its integer value in the character
>   set to the feature as another attribute.
>
> This can be used to obtain the ASCII code of any character, including
>   non-printable ones.